# Am told variable has not been initialized

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to create a code that will determine the cost of a phone bill.

Here is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneBill
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  // Create Scanner
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  //Declare variables
  double minutes, nightm, daym, totalminutes, totalcost, daycost, nightcost;
  int account;

  //Obtain account number
  System.out.println("Enter your account number: ");
  account = input.nextInt(); 

  //Determine service
  System.out.println("Enter r for regular service or p for premium service: ");
  char service = input.next(".").charAt(0);

  //Logic for regular service
  if (service == 'r')
     System.out.println("Enter number of minutes talked: ");
     minutes = input.nextDouble();

     if (minutes >= 50)
     totalcost = (10.00 + ((minutes - 50) * 0.20));

     else
     totalcost = (10.00);

  //Logic for premium service
  else if (service == 'p')
     System.out.println("Enter number of minutes used from 6:00AM to 6:00PM");
     daym = input.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter number of minutes used from 6:00PM to 6:00AM");
     nightm = input.nextDouble();

  //Obtain cost for daytime minutes
     if (daym < 75)
        daycost = 0;
     else
        daycost = ((daym - 75) * .10);

  //Obtain cost for night minutes
     if (nightm < 100)
        nightcost = 0;
     else
        nightcost = ((nightm - 100) * .05);

  //Obtain total cost of premium service

  totalcost = daycost + nightcost;      

  //Display account
  System.out.println ("The account number is: " + account);

  //Display service type
  if (service == 'r')
     System.out.println ("You have selected regular service");

  else if (service == 'p')
     System.out.println ("You have selected premium service");

  //Display results
  if (service == 'r')
     System.out.println ("Total minutes used is " + minutes);
     System.out.println ("Total ammount due is $" + totalcost);     
  else if (service == 'p')
     System.out.println ("Minutes used during the day is: " + daym);
     System.out.println ("Minutes used during the night is: " + nightm);
     System.out.println ("Total minutes used is: " + (daym + nightm));
     System.out.println ("The amount due is: $" + totalcost);
  }
}
```

I feel like I am very close but it keeps giving me this error

```
PhoneBill.java:41: error: 'else' without 'if'
      else if (service == 'p')

PhoneBill.java:78: error: 'else' without 'if'
      else if (service == 'p')
```

I have if statements above these statements, but it is still telling me that I do not.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: I'm not a java guy, so forgive me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't there be curley brackets in your if statements?  if(test) {stuff} else {other stuff}

Comment: you need to use curly brackets `{` & `}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets on an If Else statement if the inner block of code is more than one line.  I always use brackets to increase readability of the code.

```
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

      //Declare variables
      double minutes=0, nightm=0, daym=0, totalminutes=0, totalcost=0, daycost=0, nightcost=0;
      int account;

      //Obtain account number
      System.out.println("Enter your account number: ");
      account = input.nextInt(); 

      //Determine service
      System.out.println("Enter r for regular service or p for premium service: ");
      char service = input.next(".").charAt(0);

      //Logic for regular service
      if (service == 'r'){
         System.out.println("Enter number of minutes talked: ");
         minutes = input.nextDouble();

         if (minutes >= 50)
         totalcost = (10.00 + ((minutes - 50) * 0.20));

         else
         totalcost = (10.00);

      //Logic for premium service
      }else if (service == 'p'){
         System.out.println("Enter number of minutes used from 6:00AM to 6:00PM");
         daym = input.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Enter number of minutes used from 6:00PM to 6:00AM");
         nightm = input.nextDouble();

      //Obtain cost for daytime minutes
         if (daym < 75)
            daycost = 0;
         else
            daycost = ((daym - 75) * .10);

      //Obtain cost for night minutes
         if (nightm < 100)
            nightcost = 0;
         else
            nightcost = ((nightm - 100) * .05);
      }
      //Obtain total cost of premium service

      totalcost = daycost + nightcost;      

      //Display account
      System.out.println ("The account number is: " + account);

      //Display service type
      if (service == 'r'){
         System.out.println ("You have selected regular service");

      }else if (service == 'p'){
         System.out.println ("You have selected premium service");
      }
      //Display results
      if (service == 'r'){
         System.out.println ("Total minutes used is " + minutes);
         System.out.println ("Total ammount due is $" + totalcost);     
      }else if (service == 'p'){
         System.out.println ("Minutes used during the day is: " + daym);
         System.out.println ("Minutes used during the night is: " + nightm);
         System.out.println ("Total minutes used is: " + (daym + nightm));
         System.out.println ("The amount due is: $" + totalcost);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have more than one line under an `if/else if/else` statement, you need to use curly brackets `{}`:

```
if (service == 'r') {
    // your code
} else if (service == 'p') {
    // your code
}
```

I personally always use them, but some people like to exclude them for one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your code is that you are not opening curly braces for your if, else, and else if statements. If you do not include curly braces that indicate what your if statement wants to cover, the if statement will execute only the first line after it (assuming the if statement is true). Try adding curly braces to cover the scope of your if else statements and check if your code works.

Answer (score 0):

You're just hung up on basic syntax

if(case) statements work without brackets if there's only one condition underneath

```
if(case)
    dothis();
```

If you have multiple lines you need executed by the if statement you need to surround it in curly braces.

```
if(case){
    dothis();
    dothat();
}
```

This tells the program to call dothis(), and dothat() when the case is met.

I reccommend closing all of your if/else statements in braces as it helps you avoid this problem entirely.